# Rebuilding an ICollection after MVC edit?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If my model `Product` has a member `ICollection<ProductOption>` how do I rebuild my `Product` *with the member collection* in my `Controller.Edit(...)` method on post back from `Edit`?

(We can assume we never add or remove an option, only ever edit.)

Razor:

```
@model Models.Products.Product    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GlobalLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>         
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <legend>Product</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>        
    @foreach (ProductOption option in Model.Options)
    {
        <div style="border:1px solid black; margin: 5px; padding:5px 7px;">
            @Html.Partial("_ProductOptionInput", option)
        </div>
    }    
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{           
    var p = _repository.ById(id);
    UpdateModel<Product>(p);

    _repository.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");          
}
```

partial view:

```
@modelModels.Products.ProductOption

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>ProductOption</legend>    
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)    
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Term)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**UPDATE**

My `FormCollection` in `ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)` is essentially a dictionary, so it has the `ProductOption` values for one of the updated `ProductOption`s but not the rest of them as the keys (ie the `ProductOption`s property names) can't be repeated in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following in the Razor view and it works like a charm!

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Options.ToList()[0], templateName: "ProductOptionInput", htmlFieldName: "Options[0]")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Options.ToList()[1], templateName: "ProductOptionInput", htmlFieldName: "Options[1]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to write your own model binder (either for `ICollection<ProductOption>` or one that pulls your entity out of the database instead of instantiating a new instance), or you can NOT take the model in as a parameter, and instead, pull it out of the database in your action method, then call `TryUpdateModel` from the controller.

HTH